# Help with whether series converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

how can you tell if

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(2n-1)!!^{1/5}}{(2n)!!^{1/5}}$

converges or not? I tried Raabe's test but didn't get anywhere. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This equals $\sum\left(\frac{(2n)!}{4^n(n!)^2}\right)^{1/5}$ and you can use Stirling's approximation.

Comment: Just so that I'm sure of the answer, I get that a_n = (n*pi)^(1/10) and therefore is divergent, right?

Comment: I suppose you meant $a_n\approx \frac{1}{\sqrt[10]{n\pi }}$

Comment: Yes, sorry, still new to the math typing here.

Comment: It was just the sign of the exponent which was looking wrong ! Cheers